# Calculate margin-top for an element

Tags: html, css

I need to place my text with 100px margin from top, like that:

[image]

Does anyone know how to do it ? Font-size is 24pt, bold.

Comment: show us your HTML and CSS you already have. Tell us which DIV you want to change the margin from only then can we help.

Comment: Is the margin-top css element not good enough for the task?

Comment: `margin-top: 76px;` ?

Comment: @somethinghere : Are you seriously removing 24(pt) to 100 (px) ??

Comment: @EdenSource thats how his image looks (as in, the 'margin-top' is the text baseline in the image if you look at the green lines)...

Comment: @somethinghere : Sure ! you're right, but 76px cannot be the result of 100px-24pt, as long as 1pt isn't equal to 1px

Comment: Also, the baseline may not be the bottom of the glyph.

Comment: I’d use a 100px high container element, and absolutely position the text element at the bottom of that. (The baseline issue @Paulie_D just mentioned might still be a problem though – it depends on how “exact” you need it to be.)

Comment: @EdenSource Okay, then I'd suggest the following: `margin-top: calc(100px - 1em)`. The baseline issue is very different for everything, but lets assume that a font of 24pt height has its baseline at 24pt...

Answer (score 1):

Based on the suggestion from CBroe in the comments, the solution would seem to be a div of 100px tall with an absolutely positioned text element (say a parapraph) at the bottom.

I've adjusted the line-height by/to `.66em` as this seems to work to align the text at most font-sizes.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
div {
  height: 100px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;
  position: relative;
}
div p {
  font-size: 24pt;
  font-family: serif;
  line-height: .66em; /* possible "magic number" */
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Contacts</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a container div positionned at 100px from the top.

Another div inside the container, containing the text, absolutely positionned with `bottom:100%;`and that seems to work

*HTML :*

```
<div class="textWrapper">
    <div class="text">Contact</div>
</div>
```

*CSS*

```
.textWrapper {
    position:relative;
    margin-top:100px;
    display:block;
    border-bottom:1px dashed #333;
}
.text {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:100%;
    background:#aaa;
    display:block;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ncqm4x33/)